# TortoiseSVN - Committing from old revision

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, sourceforge

Right now, I'm working with a project on SourceForge. Using SVN, checking out the latest revision results in this error at some point:

```
REPORT of '/p/myproject/code-0/!svn/vcc/default':
Could not read chunk size: Secure connection truncated (https://svn.code.sf.net)
```

I checked out the revision just before it, made some changes and then wanted to commit that in hopes of getting rid of this error.

The only problem is that Tortoise won't allow me to check in anything that's modified from an older revision and insist that I must update first, which isn't possible due to the above error. How do I get around this?

Answer (score 0):

Answers to [similar SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2324187/395718) could provide more insight. One possible solution is to checkout fresh copy, manually copy there all changed files, and commit that.

Comment: Checking out a fresh copy doesn't work because of the secure connection truncated error.

Comment: Find a way to fix the problem. You can't work around it. Google for fixes. Try updating one folder at the time, or ,heck, one file at the time.

Comment: All that failed. I think I just need to avoid SourceForge from now on, as the only thing Google showed me is a bunch of other people complaining about the problem with no cure-all.